# What is the best way to include scripts into projects?

Tags: azure-devops

Our team is new to administering Azure DevOps. With the main "devops" team beginning to write automated tasks for processes that are not handled by build/release tasks, the question has arisen as the best way to facilitate this.

Currently we are storing our scripts into a repository in our own collection/project. We want to begin using the scripts as part of the build and release processes in other projects in other collections. What is the best way to get these scripts into part of the release pipeline to run as a task?

For example, I need to run a powershell script on a release server to modify content of an application after release. My thought is that I need to have a release pipeline setup for my scripts that deploy to a specific location. As part of the build process of the application, I will copy that script into the application staging folder so it can be packaged with the artifact. As part of the release pipeline, I will execute the script and then have a task that will delete the script from the release folder.

Does this sound like the best way to handle this, or is there a better, more efficient and preferred way of handling this?

Comment: Turn scripts into versioned packages.

Comment: As Daniel said, you can either create packages that are shared in something like an artifact feed (e.g. NuGet allows you to package up into .zip files). You can also point releases to multiple artifact sources from other projects directly, but may be easier for the first one.

Comment: The issue that I have is that the devops team are full administrators over the build and release pipelines, the developers have no control over modification, nor should this script be part of their project. 

What would be the best process to add the necessary tasks to collect this script from a package feed and provide it for the application being released. 

Essentially while the application is being deployed, a simultaneous process should grab this script from nuget and copy it to the release server, run, and be deleted.